# ::set-output name=dir::sth in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-actions

is there any equivalent of

```sh
::set-output name=dir::sth
```

in python?

I've found module `sh` and I'm able to set it like this:

```py
from sh import echo

echo(f"::set-output name=dir::sth")
```

but I'm wondering if there is any build in solution in python.

Comment: It would help to note what `::set-output name=dir::sth` does and what you're trying to achieve in Python.

Comment: Are you looking for the `print` built-in function?

Comment: The ``print`` statement not working in GitHub Action like ``::set-output name=dir::sth``.
For example, in Github Action I have a step:
```yaml
- name: Set selected color
        run: echo '::set-output name=SELECTED_COLOR::green'
        id: random-color-generator
      - name: Get color
        run: echo "The selected color is ${{ steps.random-color-generator.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}"
```
And I start thinking is there any option in python to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python `subprocess` module is part of the standard library. I had success with it in GitHub actions by calling its `Popen` function:

```
    steps:
      - name: Create matrix object
        id: create-matrix
        shell: python
        run: |
          from os import getenv
          from subprocess import Popen
          import json
          matrix_obj = {"prod-environment":[], "nice-app":[], "app-platform": []}
          if getenv("ENV_PRODUCTION").lower() == "true":
            matrix_obj["prod-environment"].append("production")
          ...
          if getenv("APP_GA").lower() == "true":
            matrix_obj["nice-app"].append("ga")
          matrix_str = f'::set-output name=matrix::{json.dumps(matrix_obj)}'
          print(f"Final matrix string: {matrix_str}") 
          Popen(['echo', matrix_str], bufsize=1)
        env:
          ENV_PRODUCTION: ${{inputs.env-production}}
          APP_GA: ${{inputs.app-ga}} 
          ...
```